# Sorting Rows while appending data in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I am appending data in an existing csv file using below code; I need to sort the new data with ascending date. Please advise how can I do it?

```
data.to_csv(path, mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add more informatino such as sample dataset, your current code, and a desired from of output.

Comment: Just sort the dataframe `data` before calling `to_csv`... So something like: `data.sort_values(by='date').to_csv(`.. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html for more

Comment: You mean you want to sort the existing csv file after appending all the data?

Comment: @Phoenix yes. After appending the new dataframe, the csv file should be sorted by date.

Comment: @Mohit, the best way to do it. Read the csv file to a dataframe and then append all your rows and then sort this dataframe in a descend order and finally overwrite the same csv file by your dataframe. You can do it?